# Continuous WebJob randomly restarts

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I run a continuous WebJob in my WebApp. What I have found is that it can randomly restart.
I've checked my web app settings and "Always On" is turned on. I have no triggers that can cause a reboot.
This is an empty web app, creating from scratch. All I have done is just published my continuous WebJob.
How can I prevent this random reboots?

As I see from App Insight it restarts after 10 minutes from the first run

```
2/9/2021, 12:46:45 PM - TRACE
Checking for active containers
Severity level: Information

2/9/2021, 12:46:45 PM - TRACE
Job host started
Severity level: Information

2/9/2021, 12:46:45 PM - TRACE
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
Severity level: Warning

2/9/2021, 12:46:45 PM - TRACE
Starting JobHost
Severity level: Information


2/9/2021, 12:36:44 PM - TRACE
2: Change Feed Processor: Processor_Container2 with Instance name: 4b94336ff47c4678b9cf4083a60f0b3bf1cd9f77ce7d501100a9d4e60bd87e8e has been started
Severity level: Information

2/9/2021, 12:36:37 PM - TRACE
1: Change Feed Processor: Processor_Container1 with Instance name: 4b94336ff47c4678b9cf4083a60f0b3bf1cd9f77ce7d501100a9d4e60bd87e8e has been started
Severity level: Information

2/9/2021, 12:36:32 PM - TRACE
Checking for active containers
Severity level: Information

2/9/2021, 12:36:32 PM - TRACE
Job host started
Severity level: Information
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I also saw [your case in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/265232/continuous-webjob-randomly-restarts.html), if `ajkuma-MSFT`'s answer useful to you, or you have solved the issue, you can post your solution as answer to help more forum users.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly review the Jobs and logs to isolate the issue further:

For continuous WebJobs - **Console.Out** and **Console.Error** are routed to the "application logs", they will show up as file or blob depends on your configuration of the application logs (similar to your WebApp).

Kindly check this document for more details - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#logging

I have seen cases, where having unnecessary app settings on the configuration blade of WebJobs on the portal caused reboots.
Kindly identify and remove unnecessary app settings as required (as a test).

Also, kindly see if this setting is present ‘`**WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIM**E` ‘-Timeout in seconds between when a continuous job's process goes down (for any reason) and the time we re-launch it again (Only for continuous jobs).

On the App Service, In the left navigation, click on **Diagnose and solve problems** – Checkout the tile for “`**Diagnostic Tools`**” > “Availability and Performance” & "Best Practices". /Review the WebJob details (screenshot below).

Just to isolate, kindly see if setting **singleton** helps. If a continuous job is set as singleton it'll run only on a single instance opposed to running on all instances. By default, it runs on all instances.

```
 {


  "is_singleton": true
  }
```

Refer this doc- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#set-a-continuous-job-as-singleton

[image]

P.S. To benefit the community/copying the answer from our discussion on [Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/265232/continuous-webjob-randomly-restarts.html).